# Replace repeated letters using Regular expression in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a string like :

```
      String s = "hellllooooo howwwwwww areeeeeee youuuuuuu";
```

I want to discard the repeated letters and want to get :

```
     "helloo howw aree youu"
```

I have done the matching using ::

```
        matches(".*([a-z])\\1{3,}.*"
```

But how can I replace the helloooooooo to helloo and the others ?

Comment: If I may ask: I haven't seen "\\1" in a regexp pattern before, what does it do?

Comment: how about using 'for'? trace from index 0-s.length() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of the following produces the result you want:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([a-z])\\1+", "$1$1");

s = s.replaceAll("(([a-z])\\2)\\2*", "$1");
```